# Add data to existing data in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `tblActivities`. There are two fields `ID` and `Attendees`.

```
ID       Attendees
1        Jon Jhonson
2        Ive Iveson
```

Which PHP function or MySQL statement do I need to use to get to this result:

```
ID       Attendees
1        Jon Jhonson, Ive Iveson, Adam Adamer
2        Ive Iveson
```

In other words, how can I add new data to existing data in my database?

Comment: You probably need to supply the linking table information, you should have another table which shows which activities were attended

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need something like:

```
UPDATE tblActivities
SET Attendees = CONCAT(Attendees, "Ive Iveson, Adam Adamer")
WHERE id = 1;
```

But maybe you should change the database layout. It is preferable to have only one value in one field. You could find more information under http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization.

Answer (score 1):

use mysql's update statement. If you want to exeute through php then

first get the existing value using select statement,

```
SELECT Attendees from <table-name> WHERE ID = 1
```

you will get attendees existing value, put it in a php variable, now concatenate your value..
and then update,

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET Attendees=<new-value>
WHERE ID=1
```

you would have to use the php's mysql functions to run the above queries

Answer (score 0):

I think you're better off restructuring. Make a table:

```
ID (primary key)
ACTIVITY_ID (foreign key to activity table)
ATTENDEE (foreign key to USERS table)
```

Then select everything from that event and concat in PHP.

```
$q =  mysql_query( 'SELECT ATTENDEE FROM tblActivities '.
                   'WHERE ACTIVITY_ID = $activity_id' );

$attendees = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $q ) )
{
    $attendees[] = $row['attendee'];
}
$attendees =implode( ' ', $attendees );
```