# How to append to database column value with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I have an update query which I use for keeping log of actions by appending to existing column data.
It works fine if directly executed from phpmyadmin but doesn't work from Codeigniter. Please help.

```
$query=$this->db->set('log','CONCAT(log,"check")',FALSE);
$query=$this->db->where('label_id',3)->update('labels_table');
```

Above query executes but instead of appending, it replaces the content of `log`(**Type=text**)

Comment: This looks like it might help you do just that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162509/add-data-to-existing-data-in-mysql-database. Make sure you read it all :)

Comment: @TimBrownlaw Thanks for suggestion but it doesn't answer my question. why is it not working in codeigniter( active records)?

Comment: Found the issue. it was to do with my 'replace' statement which I was executing before this query. it was wiping out the log field. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As a debugging helper, you could replace `$this->db->update('labels_table');`  with `echo $this->db->get_compiled_update('labels_table');` to get the compiled update statement without executing the query itself.